# where from can I get the Futura font for Russian language?

Tags: fonts

Is there a Futura font for Russian language and if so how can I get it and how may I enable it in OS X?

Comment: There's a version of Futura PT, which has Cyrillic letters. Just search for it in google, you'll find it.

Answer (score 1):

ParaType's Futura (Futura PT) includes Cyrillic characters. You can get it from [fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/font/paratype/futura-pt)

[image: Futura PT Cyrillic Characters]

As for how you can enable it in OS X, I'm not really sure, since I don't use Mac, but I guess when you install this font it will appear as another font (apart from the standard Futura font), so you just select the Futura PT font and type away...